# ¿Cómo añadir efecto LightBox a imágenes creadas en Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: php, wordpress

Básicamente me gustaría saber cómo puedo añadir el efecto lightbox a unas imágenes creadas en Advanced Custom Fields. He estado buscando distintas maneras, pero no he conseguido que funcione ninguna. Me gustaría poder implementarlo en el código de la plantilla. O bien, aplicarle un script para que las imágenes más pequeñas aparezcan en el lugar de otra imagen mayor (por ejemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tab_img_gallery)

Ésta es la URL: http://acciwagen.com/vehiculos/coche-1/

Éste es el código:

```
<?php

$image = get_field('primera_imagen');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

<img class="card-img-top2" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo 
$image['alt']; ?>" onclick="myFunction(this);" />

<?php endif; ?>

<?php

$image1 = get_field('segunda_imagen');

if( !empty($image1) ): ?>

<img class="card-img-top2" src="<?php echo $image1['url']; ?>" alt="<?php 
echo $image1['alt']; ?>"/>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php

$image2 = get_field('tercera_imagen');

if( !empty($image2) ): ?>

<img class="card-img-top2" src="<?php echo $image2['url']; ?>" alt="<?php 
echo $image2['alt']; ?>"/>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php

$image3 = get_field('cuarta_imagen');

if( !empty($image3) ): ?>

<img class="card-img-top2" src="<?php echo $image3['url']; ?>" alt="<?php 
echo $image3['alt']; ?>"/>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

**Edito**

El functions.php está así:

```
function my_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deseas se puede conseguir de manera bastante sencilla usando **Javascript**. Te creo un ejemplo para que luego lo traslades a tu código.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.imagen').click(function() {
      $('.imagen-grande').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

```css
.imagen-grande {
  width: 700px;
}

.imagen {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imagen-grande" class="imagen-grande" src="https://cdn2.royalcanin.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/imagencabeceraconsejosadiestramientogatitos.png">
<img id="imagen-1" class="imagen" src="https://st3.depositphotos.com/5505850/15413/i/1600/depositphotos_154130148-stock-photo-tender-kitten-isolated.jpg">
<img id="imagen-2" class="imagen" src="https://www.hillspet.be/content/dam/cp-sites/hills/hills-pet/en_us/exported/cat-care/routine-care/images/M5T9649ashx.jpg.rendition.220.270.jpg">
<img id="imagen-3" class="imagen" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/voren1/voren11710/voren1171000012/87333614-dos-peque%C3%B1os-gatitos-aislados-en-un-fondo-blanco-.jpg">
```

Lo que hago es, mediante una función `onclick` en las imágenes pequeñas (a través de la clase `.imagen`) asignarle el atributo `src` de la imagen **clickeada** al de la imagen grande.

Este tipo de eventos se ejecutan de parte del cliente (en este caso el navegador), por lo que con **PHP** no podrías resolverlo. Para agregarlo a tu plantilla tan solo tendrías que añadir una función que haga esto a uno de los `.js` que cargues.

**EDIT**

Edité para envolver la función en una `$(document).ready(function()`, para evitar que la  función trate de buscar un elemento en el DOM que todavía no cargó.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Cómo podría implementarlo en el php? Es que soy bastante novato y aún no comprendo bien estos asuntos.

Comment: Justo acabo de editar mi respuesta aportando el como podrías implementarlo. Si le añades en tu código a la imagen grande la clase **imagen-grande**, a las pequeñas la clase **imagen** y copipasteas la función que utilizo dentro de uno de los .js que cargues en tu plantilla debería de valerte. **EDIT** Para que funcione el script debes cargar también la librería de Jquery en el head de tu Web.

Comment: He añadido las clases a las imágenes. He creado un archivo script.js, pero no sé si lo estoy enlazando bien. Voy a editar el post, por si quieres echarle un vistazo.

Comment: Estos son los scripts que tengo cargados en el header.php `<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>`

Comment: Sigo sin conseguir que funcione. He dado los siguientes pasos: Primero, he copiado el script que me has facilitado en el archivo .js que tenía en el proyecto, lo he añadido al functions.php, y he cargado la librería de JQuery en el header.php. Después, he añadido las clases a cada imagen, pero sigo sin ver resultados. Qué estoy haciendo mal o dejando de hacer? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Es difícil depurar tu código con tan solo los datos que has puesto aquí. Podrías ponerle un **alert('ENTRA')** al inicio del fichero .js en el que has pegado mi función para ver si efectivamente lo estás cargando.

Comment: Gracias por responder de nuevo, y perdona las molestias que te pueda estar causando. He probado lo que me has comentado, y efectivamente no aparece nada, por lo que no debe estar cargándose correctamente.

Comment: Podrías estar teniendo problemas en la ruta relativa que usas para cargar <script src="js/script.js"></script>. Verifica que efectivamente está bien referenciada la dirección del fichero. Podrías probar a usar una ruta absoluta si ves que no das con ello.

Comment: He conseguido enlazar bien el script, ya aparece el alert. Pero todavía no funciona el tema de las imágenes.

Comment: Seguramente esté poniendo las clases de forma errónea en las imágenes. La imagen grande está así : `<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails', array('class'=>'img-fluid'), array('id'=>'imagen-grande'));} ?>`y las pequeñas así: `$image = get_field('primera_imagen');

  if( !empty($image) ): ?>

   <img id="imagen" class="card-img-top2" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

 <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Estás poniendo las clases de mi script como atributo **id** no como **class**.

Comment: He probado a ponerlas como clase también, es decir, por ejemplo: `$image = get_field('primera_imagen'); if( !empty($image) ): ?> <img class="card-img-top2 imagen" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /> <?php endif; ?>` pero aún así no funciona.

Comment: Prueba a ponerle un alert en la primera línea dentro de mi función, para ver si el evento onclick se está llamando correctamente.

Comment: Se lo he añadido y no aparece el alert.

Comment: Vale, creo que ya sé lo que te puede estar pasando. Voy a modificar mi respuesta para indicarte la manera en la que tienes que cargar el script.

Comment: Editada respuesta.

Comment: ¡Problema solucionado! Un millón de gracias por tu ayuda y paciencia.

Comment: ¡Me alegro mucho! Si te ha valido finalmente haz al favor de marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que la pregunta quede cerrada y que a alguien que le ocurra algo similar sepa que tuvo solución ^^